# Does nature perform optimal linear quadratic control?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, optimization

Given any [linear quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic%E2%80%93Gaussian_control) [control problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control)
$$\min \sum_t c_x(x_t, t) + c_u(u_t, t)$$
where $u_t$ is a "control variable" (think of it as an adjustable velocity) and $x_t$ is a "state variable" (think of it as location), and $c_x(\cdot, t), c_u(\cdot, t)$ are positive-definite quadratic functions for any $t$.

This is formally very similar to the Hamiltonian principle, in the special case where the Lagrangian has the form $L = T - V$:
$$\delta \int (T - V) dt =0 $$
Usually, $T$ is just a quadratic function in velocity, thus we can interpret it as $c_u(u_t, t)$. However, it is somewhat more difficult to interpret $V$ as $-c_x(x_t, t)$, since if we want to say that nature is performing optimal control, we expect the system to stabilize, and that means that the potential function $V(x)$ should be a positive-definite quadratic function in $x$. This however makes it impossible for $V(x_t, t) = -c_x(x_t, t)$.

Still, I find this somewhat attractive as an analogy: nature as linear quadratic optimal controller.